# Postgres User Defined Types and allocating memory correctly

Tags: c, postgresql, memory-management

I'm writing an extension for postgres which includes creating a new variable-length base type, however I'm having some difficulty understanding the semantics of SET_VARSIZE.

Take the following example code, this doesn't precisely reflect my use case but it illustrates the point.

```
typedef struct another_struct 
{
  char *a;
  char *b;
} another_struct;

typedef struct test_struct
{
  char vl_len_[4];
  another_struct *data;
} test_struct;
```

1) When allocating memory for new instances of test_struct, presumably I can simply  do the following, and it would take into account the size of the variable-length member vl_len_?

```
test_struct *t = palloc0(sizeof(struct test_struct));
```

2) Because both members of another_struct have variable lengths, I assume I also need to keep track of how much memory was allocated for both fields in order to pass the right length to SET_VARSIZE?

3) Do I also need to take into account the size of the another_struct pointer when calling SET_VARSIZE?

I'm thinking the final call to SET_VARSIZE would look something like this

```
SET_VARSIZE(t, sizeof(struct test_struct) + sizeof(struct another_struct) + a_and_b_length);
```

Is this close to being correct? Apologies for any mistakes, I'm rather new to programming in C.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it that way with just a regular pointer. All the memory has to be together after the size member.

```
typedef struct another_struct 
{
  char a[FLEXIBLE_ARRAY_MEMBER];
  char b[FLEXIBLE_ARRAY_MEMBER];
} another_struct;

typedef struct test_struct
{
  char vl_len_[4];
  another_struct data;
} test_struct;
```

and you have to know the actual size of your data now.

```
test_struct *t = palloc0(VARHDRSZ + size_of_a + size_of_b);
SET_VARSIZE(t, VARHDRSZ + size_of_a + size_of_b );
memcpy(t->data.a, src_a, size_of_a);
memcpy(t->data.b, src_b, size_of_b);
```

The example in the docs only has one field, so I'm only presuming this works this way.
There might be other issues with the indirection.
source: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-c.html

Comment: Looking at the source code of the jsonb implementation, it seems like a valid approach, specifically this line of code https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/d9cdb1ba9e66039d0f4c037a7ae6e2839e9652d6/src/include/utils/jsonb.h#L215

Comment: Having looked at various different extensions that include variable-length data types, most seem to store the on-disk representation in a binary format (jsonb's JEntry is defined as just an int), is this a requirement for performance reasons or would the approach you suggested be "good enough"?

Comment: Also presumably a self-referential struct wouldn't be possible, given that you said pointers are not allowed in a varlena struct? Is there any source on this?

Comment: I think self-referencial pointers should be fine, as long as all the memory is together and you tell it the correct memory size.